# Netcdf files created with fortran

Tags: fortran, netcdf

I use fortran to create netcdf files. I have this problem: I have no choice than to use a loop to define some of my variables (and assign the attribute values). Then, when I want to provide the values of the variables (i.e, nf90_put_var), it only recalls the last variable that has been defined... I have tried many things to resolve the problem but I didn't succeed. Someone could help me ?

Here is a small part of my script:

```
DO IP=1,N(PTS)
   Param_name='var1'
   params(I,IPTS)=INT(I,IPTS,IP) 

! Define Netcdf Variable
  IERREU = nf90_def_var(ncid, Param_name, nf90_real, dimid, ParVarID)

 IF (IERREU.NE.0) THEN
       CALL check_err (IERREU)
       STOP 
 ENDIF
ENDDO

! End define mode
IERREU = nf90_enddef(ncid)

IF (IERREU.NE.0) THEN
    CALL check_err (IERREU)
    STOP 
ENDIF

! Write the data in netcdf
 IERREU = nf90_put_var(ncid,parvarID, params)

 IF (IERREU.NE.0) THEN
     CALL check_err (IERREU)
     STOP 
ENDIF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must store the `parVarId` for each variable separately. Perhaps store it in an array. You now overwrite it with each call to `nf90_def_var`.

```
integer ParVarIds(N(PTS))

DO IP=1,N(PTS)
     ...
     IERREU = nf90_def_var(ncid, Param_name, nf90_real, dimid, ParVarIds(IP))

     ...
ENDDO

DO IP=1,N(PTS)
     ...
     IERREU = nf90_put_var(ncid,parVarIds(IP), something)

     ...
ENDDO
```